# Проблема с API-интерфейсом Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api, google-maps, геолокация

Вроде все проверил, в консоли никаких ошибок и предупреждений нет, но карта с моим местоположением не выводится. 
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>Document</title>
          <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDpvqbVs5atjOZ6g5BAnP6fKV6FG_EztJM"></script>
          <script src="myLoc.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
     <div id="location">
         Your location will go here. 
     </div>
     <div id="distance">
          Distance from WickedlySmart HQ will go here.
     </div>
     <div id="map">
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Код нужно тестировать с сервера.

```
    var ourCoords = {
    latitude: 47.624851,
    longitude: -122.52099
};


window.onload = getMyLocation;

function getMyLocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayError);
    }
    else {
        alert("Oops, no geolocation support");
    }
}

function displayLocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var div = document.getElementById("location");
    div.innerHTML = "You are at Latitude :" + latitude  + ", Longitude: " + longitude;

    var km = computeDistance(position.coords, ourCoords);
    var distance = document.getElementById("distance");
    distance.innerHTML = "You are " + km + " km form the WickedlySmart HQ";

    showMap(position.coords);
}

function displayError(error) {
    var errorTypes = {
        0: "Unknown error",
        1: "Permission denied  by user",
        2: "Position is not available",
        3: "Request timed out"
    };
    var errorMessage = errorTypes[error.code];
    if (error.code == 0 || error.code == 2) {
        errorMessage = errorMessage + " " + error.message;
    }
    var div = document.getElementById("location");
    div.innerHTML = errorMessage;
}

// --------------------- Ready Bake ------------------
//
// Uses the Spherical Law of Cosines to find the distance
// between two lat/long points
//
function computeDistance(startCoords, destCoords) {
    var startLatRads = degreesToRadians(startCoords.latitude);
    var startLongRads = degreesToRadians(startCoords.longitude);
    var destLatRads = degreesToRadians(destCoords.latitude);
    var destLongRads = degreesToRadians(destCoords.longitude);

    var Radius = 6371; // radius of the Earth in km
    var distance = Math.acos(Math.sin(startLatRads) * Math.sin(destLatRads) + 
                    Math.cos(startLatRads) * Math.cos(destLatRads) *
                    Math.cos(startLongRads - destLongRads)) * Radius;

    return distance;
}

function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
    radians = (degrees * Math.PI)/180;
    return radians;
}

// ------------------ End Ready Bake -----------------

var map;

function showMap(coords) {
    var googleLatAndLong = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude,coords.longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center:googleLatAndLong,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что не были заданы стили. 
В файле css нужно задать ширину и высоту блока.

```
    body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
}
form, div#location, div#distance {
    padding: 5px;
}

div#map {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Внимательным нужно быть, уважаемый )))